# How to declare dynamic form field defaults inside a Coldfusion CFC?

Tags: forms, dynamic, coldfusion, cfc

I'm looking for a way to declare form default values dynamically in a CFC, I'm calling via AJAX. The current CFC sends orders, which I need to break down into sub-orders.

I had been using this:

```
 <!--- static defaults --->
 <cffunction name="Defaults" access="public" returntype="struct" output="false" 
    hint="Assign default values to instance">
    <cfscript>
        var formDefaults = {
              versenden=""
            , speichern="" 
            ...
        }
    </cfscript>
    <cfreturn formDefaults />
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="Commit" access="public" returntype="struct" output="false" hint="database handler">

 <!--- add dynamic form fields --->
 <cfscript>             
    var LOCAL = {};
    variables.defs = THIS.Defaults();
 </cfscript>
 <cfloop collection="#VARIABLES.Instance.FormData#" item="formField">
    <cfscript>
        if (   LEFT(formField, 5) EQ "MENGE" 
            OR LEFT(formField, 3) EQ "EAN" 
            OR LEFT(formField, 12) EQ "BESTELL_TEXT" 
            OR LEFT(formField, 10) EQ "BESTELLTYP" 
            ...
          ) {
          variables.defs[formField]="";
        }
    </cfscript>
</cfloop>
<cfscript>
    structAppend(variables.defs, VARIABLES.Instance.FormData);                  
    LOCAL.Basket = variables.defs;  
</cfscript>

...
```

So I first declare static form fields (single instance only) and then try to dynamically append dynamic form fields to my array, which might be transferred multiple times (`MENGE38, MENGE39, MENGE40` etc)

While this works ok, I need to add another counting element to my form-names, so I would have to change `MENGE` to something like `counter.MENGE` or `MENGE.counter` which will then send form values like this:

```
MENGE.1.38
MENGE.1.40
MENGE.1.41
MENGE.2.37
```

With the counter denoting the sub-order, this field is used for.

Problem is, this breaks my dynamic form field declaration and I don't understand why. I'm getting the following errors:

```
Diagnose: Element MENGE.1 is undefined in a CFML structure referenced as part of an expression.
```

**Question:**
Can anyone give me a hint on what the problem might be? Do I have to param the form fields on the HTML page as well (shouldn't have to)?

Thanks!

**EDIT**:
Problem was in my validate function, I also need to declare the modifications I did above. The new function looks like this:

```
<cffunction name="Validate" access="public" returntype="array" output="false" hint="validate form inputs and return an array of faulty field names.">
   <cfscript>
     var LOCAL = {};
     var double = structNew();
     double.form = VARIABLES.Instance.FormData;
     double.criteria = VARIABLES.Instance.Validation;
  </cfscript>

  <!--- add dynamic form fields for validation... I FORGOT TO UPDATE THIS--->
  <cfloop collection="#VARIABLES.Instance.FormData#" item="formField">
     <cfscript>
        if (   LEFT(formField, 5) EQ "MENGE" 
            OR LEFT(formField, 10) EQ 'BESTELLTYP'
            OR LEFT(formField, 3) EQ "EAN" 
            OR LEFT(formField, 12) EQ "BESTELL_TEXT" 
            ...
        ) {
           VARIABLES.Instance.Validation[formField]="pass";
        }
     </cfscript>
  </cfloop>
  <!--- Get error names and type --->
  <cfinvoke component="form_validate" method="validate_fields" double="#double#" returnvariable="validation_errors"></cfinvoke>
  <cfset LOCAL.ErrorMessages = validation_errors />
  <cfreturn LOCAL.ErrorMessages />
```

Because I did not add the new updated the if-clause in this function, I was getting the error.

Comment: I think the problem is being caused because you are using periods as part of the form field names.  This stops each field from being a simple element.  What happens if you use underscores instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build on Dan Bracuk's answer, use underscores (though you'd need to change the name of "BESTELL_TEXT"). Use this with a combination of listFirst, listGetAt, and listLast to determine field name structure, using underscore as delimiter. Note how I cleaned up your big IF a bit using list function. This code as written probably doesn't do what you need, but wanted to illustrate the concepts without having to understand your business need.

```
<cfscript>
var orders=structNew();
item=listFirst(formField,'_');
orderNames = "MENGE,EAN,BESTELLTEXT,BESTELLTYPE";
if (listFindNoCase(orderNames,item,'_')){
    if (!structKeyExists(orders,item)){
        // initialize item
        orders[item]=structNew();
    }
    orderID="";
    subOrderId="";
    if (listLen(formField,'_') gt 1) {
        orderID=listGetAt(formField,2,'_');
    }
    if (listLen(formField,'_') eq 2) {
        orders[item][orderId]=formData[formField];
    }
    if (listLen(formField,'_') eq 3) {
        subOrderId=listLast(formField,'_');
        orders[item][orderId][subOrderId]=formData[formField];
    }

}
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Billy - the reason you owe me a beer is that my vote for your answer pushed your reputation into 4 digits.

Comment: lol @DanBracuk - hit me up next time you see me at a conference

Comment: I figured it out eventually. The `.` was one problem. I switched it to `fieldname__counter__`. Which works fine for me. Then I also forgot to update another line of code which made it work. Posted above.